# Check if any key is down in JS

Tags: javascript, input, key

Instead of googling how to detect if a specific key is pressed, I need to know if any key is pressed and return true if **any** key is down, and false if **all** keys are up.

The only way I can think of is by checking which keys are down, that's way too tedious, are there easier ways?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a keydown listener and add the keyCode to a Set. Also have a keyup listener that deletes the keyCode from the set (if it exists). Then when you need to check to see if any keys are down, check to see if the set's .size is 0 or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```js
function getKey()
{
    alert("Key is down.");
    // or return true
}

document.onkeydown = getKey;
```

Comment: this doesn't quite do what I'm looking for as I wish to check whether any key is down, not when a key is pressed, but thankyou.